# Understanding combineReducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

New to react and redux so playing around with some very simple code to see how it all works. 
When I try passing in a combineReducers method to a redux store then I get an error. If I remove the combinedReducers and pass the reducer in directly to the store all works fine.

```
let store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {reducer}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object)
>   from the React add-ons. Check the render method of App.

Why do I get an error when I use combineReducers ? What if I wanted to add more reducers I presume thats what combineReducers is there for ?

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';

let reducer = (state=0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE': 
            return state+1
    case 'DECREASE': 
            return state-1
    default: return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer:reducer
});

let store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**//app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
        let {number, increase, decrease} = this.props
        return(
                <div>
              <div>{number}</div>
              <button onClick={e=>increase()}>+</button>
              <button onClick={e=>decrease()}> - </button>
            </div>
            );
     }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => ({
  number: state
})

let mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  increase: () => dispatch({type: 'INCREASE'}),
  decrease: () => dispatch({type: 'DECREASE'})
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combine reducers takes a hash of reducers and returns a reducer. The resulting reducer represents an object of the same shape as the hash.

So, a call like this:

```
combineReducers({ name: nameReducer})
```

Would produce a state object that might look something like this:

```
{ name: 'Joe Shmo' }
```

In your example, you are producing a global state tree that looks like this:

```
{ reducer: 0 }
```

But you are trying to pull a property called `number` out of this in your `mapStateToProps`.

If you change your reducer declaration to look like this:

```
const number = (state=0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE': 
            return state+1
    case 'DECREASE': 
            return state-1
    default: return state
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    number
});
```

Then change your `mapStateToProps` to look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({number}) => ({number});
```

Your code should start working.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your explanation. So all I really needed to change was the fact that state has a key instead of just been a number. So I could just have changed let mapStateToProps = state => ({
  number: state.reducer
}) and all would have worked. Thanks for making it clearer by changing the names to number

Comment: As a matter of interest what's the difference between an object and a hash in js ? You mentioned it in your comment above.

Comment: I'd highly encourage you to read through the Redux docs thoroughly - there's lots of good information in there.  In particular, the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section describes this issue, and explains useful patterns for writing your reducer logic.

Comment: In JS (at least old versions) there are no differences between objects and hashes. New versions of JS have first-class hash objects available to you that theoretically could have different performance implications, and have convenience methods on them.

Answer (score 9):

https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos
})

export default todoApp
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
export default function todoApp(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter(state.visibilityFilter, action),
    todos: todos(state.todos, action)
  }
}
```

You could also give them different keys, or call functions differently. These two ways to write a combined reducer are equivalent:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  a: doSomethingWithA,
  b: processB,
  c: c
})
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    a: doSomethingWithA(state.a, action),
    b: processB(state.b, action),
    c: c(state.c, action)
  }
}
```

And don't forget connect each parts

```
@connect(state => ({
  reducerName: state[partStoreName]
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have also done:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { number: 0 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASE': 
            return state+1
    case 'DECREASE': 
            return state-1
    default: return state
  }
};
```